Error "An error has occurred. Try again later" when creating a new app in App Store Connect
I am trying to create a new app in App Store Connect, but I keep encountering an error message saying, "An error has occurred. Try again later."

An error has occurred. Try again later.

Despite ensuring all fields are correctly filled, the error persists.
I've attached a screenshot for reference:


So, try again later... you have nothing to do with this.

I had the same problem. I initially had an unsigned agreement in the Business section.
Once it was signed, I could proceed with creating the app.
